# How do I turn off syntax highlighting in micro text editor?

Tags: editor, syntax-highlighting, text-editor

I have recently started using micro text editor.
I would like to turn off syntax highlighting completely.

According to the micro documentation, I can create my own syntax configuration file in `~/.config/micro/syntax`. I tried to create a syntax file to turn it off, but it did not work well. I also tried to change `settings.json` at `~/.config/micro` but nothing worked.

How do I create a syntax file that turns off syntax highlighting compeletly?